# Android ML Kit Firebase FirebaseVisionText , `block.getCornerPoints() `always `return null` values

Tags: android, image-processing, firebase-mlkit

Android ML Kit Firebase FirebaseVisionText, `block.getCornerPoints()` always `return null` value. how to get readed text `polygon corner` points in firebase.

code block on success response

```
 List<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> blocks = text.getTextBlocks();
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: block corner points: " + blocks.get(i).getCornerPoints());

        List<FirebaseVisionText.Line> lines = blocks.get(i).getLines();
        for (int j = 0; j < lines.size(); j++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: line corner points: " + lines.get(j).getCornerPoints());
            List<FirebaseVisionText.Element> elements = lines.get(j).getElements();
            for (int l = 0; l < elements.size(); l++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: element corner points: " + elements.get(l).getCornerPoints());
                CloudTextGraphic cloudTextGraphic = new CloudTextGraphic(graphicOverlay,
                        elements.get(l));
                graphicOverlay.add(cloudTextGraphic);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First instantiate Point[] reference :

```
Point[] elementCornerPoints = elements.get(l).getCornerPoints();
```

Now get 4 corner points of an element:

```
for(int p=0 ; p<elementCornerPoints.length; p++){

    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: element corner points: " + elementCornerPoints[p]);
 }
```